# Altova Mapforce: Joining XML Input and conditional SQL Join using two tables

Tags: altova

I'm trying to get the following done: Using Altova Mapforce, I use an XML file with schema as a source. I want to map it to exactly the same output, but only add data to one field.

The value of the field (it's Tax) is determined using a two table SQL join with a WHERE clause over both tables. The tables are joined using foreign keys, the relation is recognized by Mapforce.

The first field of the WHERE clause comes from the first table (header type table), the second and third field from the second tables (lines type tables).

However, I cannot seem to create the logical and correct equivalent of what I am describing here. I've tried it using complex AND constructions where it then inserts the one field I would need multiple times. I've tried WHERE clauses but they fail as they never supply both tables at the same time and there seems to be no way to use a pre-specified JOINing of two tables as a source. The WHERE clause then recognizes only the fields from the first table, not the second one.

Is there an example for this? Joining two (or more) tables, using WHERE to determine the exact row, then using a value from that row?

Best wishes.